# Using li:after to attach style to custom browser-like tab

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a `ul` that I'm using for my breadcrumbs component to make tabs that will look like this (The white blocks will be text styled differently):

> [image]

I'm trying to create the slanted end of this tab using css styles for `li:after`.

```css
.breadcrumb-container {
    background: blue;
    font-family: var(--font-family-semibold);
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-block-start: 0em;
    margin-block-end: 0em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 0px;

    li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 10px 20px;

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 17px;
            font-family: var(--font-family-semibold);
        }
    }
}

ul.tabs>li {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    height: 56px;
    background: darkblue;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    max-width: 222px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #10172E;
}

ul.tabs>li>a {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $alis-white;
}

li:after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 33px;
    left: 90px;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 56px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumb-container">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab"><mat-icon>search</mat-icon></li>
        <li class="tab1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Different size Tab</a></li>
        <li class="tab2"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 2</a></li>
        
    </ul>

</div>
```

My code looks like this:

> [image]

- The **Green Triangles** are the `li:after` style slices I'm trying to connect to the end of each tab.
- I'm using `left: 90px;` in `li:after` but that's *not dynamic* and will change based on the length of the text in the tab.

### How do I connect this `li:after` style to the end of the tab *dynamically*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it `position: absolute` and stick it to the right with `right: -30px` of the parent li have `position: relative`, so no matter how long the text, it always stay at the end.

```css
.breadcrumb-container {
    background: blue;
    font-family: var(--font-family-semibold);
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-block-start: 0em;
    margin-block-end: 0em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 0px;

    li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 10px 20px;

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 17px;
            font-family: var(--font-family-semibold);
        }
    }
}

ul.tabs>li {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    height: 56px;
    background: darkblue;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    max-width: 222px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #10172E;
    position: relative;
}

ul.tabs>li>a {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $alis-white;
}

li:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    bottom: -1px;
    right: -30px;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 56px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumb-container">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab"><mat-icon>search</mat-icon></li>
        <li class="tab1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Different size Tab</a></li>
        <li class="tab2"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Tab 2</a></li>
        
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thanks so much that works like a charm! Makes sense to have the parent be local and then keep the child absolute.